# Replace a value except at the end of a line

Tags: regex, sed

So I have a text file that contains ASCII STX characters (targetable with \x02) sprinkled throughout. I want to remove them if they are NOT at the end of a line.

```
# This removes all STX characters
sed -i 's/\x02//g' foo.txt

# This removes STX characters that are at the end of a line
sed -i 's/\x02$//g' foo.txt
```

How does one remove the character if it is NOT at the end of the line?

Comment: Hint: How do you know if a given character is at the end of a given line?

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/\x02\(.\)/\1/g' foo.txt`

Comment: maybe the regex `\x02[^$]` is what you're after? Also, you probably want a look ahead to not replace the character matched by `[^$]`

Comment: or maybe `\x02(?!$)` with a negative look ahead

Comment: @isaac: Great ideas, but like you said, the character will get replaced. I don't believe sed supports look aheads.

Comment: `sed` has not `Negative Lookahead (?!\n|$)`, You must migrate to other language with similar syntax, like `perl`, for example `cat file | perl -ne 's/\x02(?!\n|$)//g; print;'`

Comment: view example https://regex101.com/r/pd25hn/1

Comment: `cat file | perl -ne 's/\x02(?!$)//g; print;'` better

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. no need explicit print, use `-p` instead of `-n`... `perl -pe 's/\x02(?!$)//g'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match and *capture* any char after one or more chars you need to remove to restore it later with a backreference:

```
sed -i 's/\x02\{1,\}\(.\)/\1/g' foo.txt
```

Here, `\x02\{1,\}` matches 1 or more chars you need to remove, `\(.\)`  will match and capture into Group 1 any char and `\1` will restore the captured char in the result.

Comment: I did notice one edge case that seems to fail. If there are two STX characters next to each other. One is not removed. It does however handle more than one STX character in a line if they are not back to back.

Comment: @david: Then extend it to match one-or-more STXs: `sed -i 's/\x02\{1,\}\(.\)/\1/g'`.  If you have the `-E` or `-r` option to `sed`, you write it using extended regular expression notation instead of needing quite so many backslashes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Spot on.

Comment: @david: Sorry, I was offline. Yes, the `\{1,\}` quantifier will match one or more occurrences of `\x02`

Comment: The answer has been updated with the mentioned changes.